# What happens when you commit a transaction after rollback?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Let’s say I have a C# class that creates a transaction for the database and then calls a stored procedure. The stored procedure returns an `int = 1` if there’s an error. And let’s say that we update a table but then return 1 because an error happened somewhere in the SP.

This then throws an exception in c#, which calls a method to rollback the transaction — but in the FINALLY block of the method, we commit the transaction.

Since the transaction was rolled back, what happens when we then call commit?

Comment: Nice questions. I will do it practically and make comments on it. I think nothing will happen because your transaction has been rollbacks already and there is nothing to commit. Have to confirm it practically

Comment: It should throw an error saying there is no active transaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you rollback the transaction, all changes made in that transactions are just... rolled back, cancelled. So your commit in finally block won't do anything, at least when you have no other transactions waiting.

I wouldn't place commit method in finally block, I'd commit the transaction at the end of try block and rollback in catch block.

Comment: I agree — it’s weird that we have a commit inside of a finally block. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, because you want to commit just in case of successfull execution, now it is like "commit no matter what happens". If answer has helped you, please accept it (optionally upvote if you fell like :) ).

Comment: Yeah, but we should definitely have the commit inside of the TRY block and not the FINALLY. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you to use transactions in your stored procedure too along with try catch block.

I have confirmed that after rollback we cannot commit the same transaction.

Make sure another transaction is not in waiting, else it will be committed.

Also don't do anything with transaction in finally block. Always use finally block to close connection , data reader etc.

Always commit in try block and do rollback in catch block.